# Is it possible to rename a file before downloading from a url?

Tags: android

I know that you can use AsyncTask to download a file, but I was wondering if you can change the name to something else before downloading. So like if the file is named abc.mp3 can the user download the file as def.mp3?

Comment: How are you planning on downloading it? `DownloadManager`? OkHttp? `HttpUrlConnection`? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new to android so I'm not too familiar with the ways to download something, but I was wondering if it was possible to do so.

Comment: I was planning on downloading from google drive if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most APIs that might be described as "downloading" require you, the programmer, to indicate where the bytes go that you download. Typically, that would be in the form of a filesystem path, which would include the filename. In general, you can choose whatever filename that you want.

It is possible that some *specific* downloading APIs might not give you the flexibility to choose the filename. For example, I have not used the Google Drive API and do not know what it offers.